# Iam still confused how time complexity is calculated

Tags: java, time-complexity

For the below code it is said that the time complexity is `O(n^2)`

If the inner loop runs for `n*n` times
and outer loop runs for n times then shouldn't it be `O(n^3)`

```
public static void func(int n){
    int sum=0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
      for(;i<n*n;i++)
       sum+=1;
     
      System.out.println(sum):
    
    }
}
```

But similarily for below code,the time complexity is `O(n^3)`

```
public static void func(int n) {
    int sum=0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
      for(int j=0;j<n*n;j++) {
        sum+=1;
        System.out.println(sum);
      }
    }
}
```

So can someone explain the reason ?

I felt that time complexity for the cases should be O(n^3) but that's not the case.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in the code and format the code as code block. You can do this by surrounding your code by three backtick characters (`\`\`\``) both on top of the code and at the bottom.

Comment: First of all can you plese format your code so that we can read it conveniently

Comment: In the first function, the outer loop will only run once, because the inner loop raises `i` past the end of the outer loop's limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in the case of the second example, the time complexity is O(n^3) since the outer loop iterates n-1 times and inner one n^2 which results in (n-1) * n^2 or n^3 - n^2 so considering constant time operations the complexity can be expressed as O(n^3).

However in the first example the complexity is only O(n^2) which reflects the number of iterations of the inner loop since the outer loop will always execute  only once. This is because the inner loop will exit with i=n*n-1 after the first iteration of outer loop which is outside the first loop's bounds (i < n).

Answer (score 1):

The first code has the time-complexity O(n^2), because we are using the same iterator `i` in both loops so it will run only when `i<n` from outer-loop, doesn't matter if we put `i<n^3 or i<n^10` in inner-loop, it will exit the both loops as soon as it becomes `i=n`.

& the second loop certainly has the time-complexity of `O(n^3)`